# Typescript Cannot find name 'XInterface'

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I have the following code, including a class and an interface. for some reason Visual Studio is yelling at me that it "can't find name 'RouteInterface'", and I have no idea why.

```
import {Student} from './student';

export interface RouteInterface{
    id: number;
    startTime: Date;
    endTime: Date;
    neighborhood: string;
    students: Student[];
    tooltip: string;
    tooltipcls: string;
    icon: string;
}


export class Route extends RouteInterface {
    id: number;
    startTime: Date;
    endTime: Date;
    neighborhood: string;
    students: Student[];
    tooltip: string;
    tooltipcls: string;
    icon: string;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use the `implements` keyword instead of the `extends` one:

```
export class Route implements RouteInterface {
  (...)
}
```